# Вопрос по bcrypt хэшированию. Веб-программирование

Tags: php, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

Предположим, что пользователь моего сайта забыл пароль и мне нужно восстановить его, но у меня стоит bcrypt хэширование. Как мне это сделать, используя веб-приложение phpmyadmin.

Comment: Отправить ему на почту ссылку, ведущую на форму ввода нового пароля. Просто нажмите «Забыл пароль» на любом сайте (хоть [прямо здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) на сайте Stack Overflow) и посмотрите как сделано у всех

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам phpmyadmin, но в его случае примерно то же самое: получить от пользователя новый пароль, захэшировать в bcrypt и записать в базу как обычно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пароль не хранится в БД в чистом виде, а хранится только хэш пароля, то восстановить его не удастся.

Хотя, конечно, попробовать можно, написав цикл, который перебирает все возможные пароли, генерит из них bcrypt хэш и проверяет на соответствие тому, что в БД (старый, добрый брутфорс), но это никогда не стоит того.

Обычная практика для восстановления пароля - замена его другим паролем.
Обычная практика для замены пароля - кнопка "Забыли пароль?" на сайте, которая по клику ведёт, допустим, на форму для ввода почты. На почту приходит секретная ссылка, при переходе по которой юзеру даётся возможность ввести новый пароль.

Допустим, вы не хотите заморачиваться с созданием функционала под "Забыли пароль?". 
Тогда, проще всего, думаю, создать нового юзера на сайте с нужным паролем и взять в phpmyadmin хэш, который для него сгенерился и вставить нужному юзеру. Но это не тру вэй, ведь вы будете знать его пароль, что нехорошо.

Можно отправить юзера на онлайн-генератор хэшей bcrypt, он там введёт пароль, скинет вам хэш, а вы замените через phpmyadmin. Но это также костыли, просто, чтобы решить одну ситуацию. Если такие ситуации будут повторяться систематически, без функционала "Забыли пароль?" вам не обойтись